# Declaring a View as a property v. Temporary Creation

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management

I have recently began creating iOS applications completely programmatically (without the interface builder) and was wondering if there was any advantage/difference in declaring a ViewController's view as a property before using it versus simply creating at the **loadview** function. Also, would I dealloc the view inside of the controllers dealloc if I am using it as a property?

i.e. this

```
- (void)loadView
{
    _rootView = [[RootView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    [self setView:self.rootView];
}
```

vs.

```
- (void)loadView
{
    RootView *rootView = [[RootView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    [self setView:rootView];
    [rootView release];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`view` already *is* a property of `UIViewController`. Declaring an extra property such as `rootView` in your example would be pointless. So your second example would be the way to go. (I'm not sure why you'd want to create a view with a width and height of zero, but that's another story.)

In this case, your `dealloc` implementation (if you provide one) should call `[super dealloc]` to ensure that the `view` property is sent a `release` message, but of course you should *always* call `[super dealloc]` in any overridden implementation of `dealloc`.

Comment: I guess that makes sense seeing as I am just setting the current view. And the reason I use the CGRectZero is that when the view controller takes the new view, it adjusts it automatically (in my case screen size).